What are the best practices for retrieving secrets from an Azure Vault in a Java/Spring Boot development environment?
I have Java/Spring Boot application that utilizes profiles. Depending on the active profile, the application accesses secrets from the corresponding Azure Vault using Managed Identity. However, Managed Identity doesn't function on a local development machine.
The current approach stores the secret in a local environment variable, allowing the application to access it within the same developer context. However, this approach carries a security risk.
What are the best practices for retrieving secrets from an Azure Vault in a local development machine?

“Best Practices” is a trigger-word for some people here, unfortunately. I suggest you rephrase. And be specific about your concerns, and the approaches you know about along with their pros and cons.

@BasilBourque Updated the question with the current approach.

if you use DefaultAzureCredential that should work for both

@Rick, which version of Java are you trying?

Yes, I agree with @Thomas.
You can retrive the secrets from Azure Keyvault using the DefaultAzureCredential in local development.
I tried the below code in Java/Spring boot to retrieve the secrets from the Azure Keyvault using DefaultAzureCredential  in local development.
Code :
KeyVaultSecretService :
package com.example.keyvaultsecrets.service;

import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.models.KeyVaultSecret;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class KeyVaultSecretService {

    @Value("${azure.keyvault.uri}")
    private String keyVaultUri;

    @Value("${azure.keyvault.secret.name}")
    private String secretName;

    public String getSecret() {
        SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
                .vaultUrl(keyVaultUri)
                .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                .buildClient();
        try {
            KeyVaultSecret keyVaultSecret = secretClient.getSecret(secretName);
            return keyVaultSecret.getValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Error retrieving secret: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}

SecretController :
package com.example.keyvaultsecrets.controller;

import com.example.keyvaultsecrets.service.KeyVaultSecretService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SecretController {

    private final KeyVaultSecretService keyVaultSecretService;
    @Autowired
    public SecretController(KeyVaultSecretService keyVaultSecretService) {
        this.keyVaultSecretService = keyVaultSecretService;
    }
    @GetMapping("/secret")
    public String getSecret() {
        return keyVaultSecretService.getSecret();
    }
}

application.properties :
azure.keyvault.uri=https://<keyvaultname>.vault.azure.net/  
azure.keyvault.secret.name=<secretName>

Terminal Output :

Browser Output :
I have retrieved the secrets from the Azure KeyVault in the browser as shown below.
http://localhost:8080/api/secret


